# Need to show person/group column in Custom List when user is admin

Tags: list, custom-list

I Need to show person/group column in custom list,when user is  valid admin or I need to automatically fill that column with  current user name.Please say me how to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to show column when user has permission/or(Admin).
The Admin column from DispForm/NewForm/EditForm page and AllItems.aspx, etc for the normal users without admin permission you need to hide, and it can be seen by the administrators, these two articles can help,

http://doitwithsharepoint.blogspot.in/2011/06/use-xslt-to-hide-columns-in-sharepoint.html

http://sharepointjim.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/sharepoint-data-view-conditional-formatting-based-on-user-permissions-ifhasrights/

you can hide columns using xslt.

For other thing to set value of column with current user,

```
<Field ID="{99ced9dc-5715-47a7-9ede-1733f027eeb4}" 
    Name="MyField" 
    DisplayName="My Field" 
    Type="User" 
    List="UserInfo" 
    UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly" 
    Required="TRUE">
    <DefaultFormula>=";#"&amp;Me</DefaultFormula>
</Field>
```

follow the below article:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343574/how-can-i-set-a-user-field-to-a-default-value-of-a-user-currently-logged-in-thro

Comment: @user3492718 cool, Please mark it as answer if it solve your query. thanks!